# How Can I get the first date on or after a given date?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am using the following function. My index is a series of dates and I am looking to get the first date or first subsequent date if the date is not available of every month. I used the following code which gets the nearest date to the first date but causes a problem when i have in this case the 31st Dec closer to the 1st Jan rather than what should be the 4th Jan.

```
df['month'] = df.index.to_numpy().astype('datetime64[M]')
def nearest(items, pivot):
    return min(items, key=lambda x: abs(x - pivot))

for n in range(len(df)):    
    d = nearest(df.index, df['month'][n])
    print(d)
```

output:

```
2020-12-31 00:00:00
2020-12-31 00:00:00
2020-12-31 00:00:00
2020-12-31 00:00:00
2020-12-31 00:00:00
2021-02-01 00:00:00
2021-02-01 00:00:00
```

Is there an easy way to amend my code so that I get `2021-01-04` rather than `2020-12-31`

```
Date        x       y       z
28/12/2020  3723.030029 3735.360107 133.990005
29/12/2020  3750.01001  3727.040039 138.050003
30/12/2020  3736.189941 3732.040039 135.580002
31/12/2020  3733.27002  3756.070068 134.080002
04/01/2021  3764.610107 3700.649902 133.520004
05/01/2021  3698.02002  3726.860107 128.889999
06/01/2021  3712.199951 3748.139893 127.720001
07/01/2021  3764.709961 3803.790039 128.360001
08/01/2021  3815.050049 3824.679932 132.429993
11/01/2021  3803.139893 3799.610107 129.190002
12/01/2021  3801.620117 3801.189941 128.5
13/01/2021  3802.22998  3809.840088 128.759995
14/01/2021  3814.97998  3795.540039 130.800003
15/01/2021  3788.72998  3768.25 128.779999
19/01/2021  3781.879883 3798.909912 127.779999
20/01/2021  3816.219971 3851.850098 128.660004
21/01/2021  3857.459961 3853.070068 133.800003
22/01/2021  3844.23999  3841.469971 136.279999
25/01/2021  3851.679932 3855.360107 143.070007
26/01/2021  3862.959961 3849.620117 143.600006
27/01/2021  3836.830078 3750.77002  143.429993
28/01/2021  3755.75 3787.379883 139.520004
29/01/2021  3778.050049 3714.23999  135.830002
01/02/2021  3731.169922 3773.860107 133.75
02/02/2021  3791.840088 3826.310059 135.729996
03/02/2021  3840.27002  3830.169922 135.759995
04/02/2021  3836.659912 3871.73999  136.300003
05/02/2021  3878.300049 3886.830078 137.350006
08/02/2021  3892.590088 3915.590088 136.029999
09/02/2021  3910.48999  3911.22998  136.619995
```

Comment: What does the dataframe look like and what should the desired output look like?

Comment: added df, desired output would be yyyy-mm-01 or where the df doesnt have 01 I would like the nearest row after the 1st of that month for example January 2021 yyyy-mm-04

Comment: I think I have solved it using d = df.index.get_loc(df['month'][n],method='backfill')